# Android Studio + cmake + OpenGL : Could NOT find OpenGL

Tags: android, android-studio, opengl-es, cmake

Under Android Studio, I have created a new project and add a new cmakelists.txt file that tries to find opengl, but I got an error message:

```
Could NOT find OpenGL (missing: OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR)
```

Does someone has an idea to solve this issue ?

Here is the cmakelists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

add_library(native-lib SHARED src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp)
find_library(log-lib log)
target_link_libraries(native-lib ${log-lib})

find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
```

Comment: Show your CMakeList.txt that attempts to find OpenGL...

Comment: I have edit the description.

Answer (score 3):

`find_package(OpenGL)` is a CMake module intended for OpenGL, not for OpenGL ES, which is what Android supports. CMake does not have a built-in module for finding OpenGL ES. You can locate it with the answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40074981/add-static-prebuilt-libraries-and-glesv2-support-to-ndk-app-in-android-studio-us]) (assuming you are using GLES2).